# Get Object from EF Collection Before Calling SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Using the Entity Framework, I have a table called `WorkSet`. I add an item to it as follows:

```
_entity.WorkSet.AddObject( new WorkSet() { Name = "Something" } );
```

When I query the table after this I receive no results.

```
_entity.WorkSet.Count() == 0 // always true
```

That is, until I call `SaveChanges`. I understand why this is the way it works, but I want to know how I can see my changes in the entity before I persist them to the database via `SaveChanges`. I hope this is a simple problem that can be solved quickly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ObjectContext.SavingChanges` event for this purpose. Within the event handler check entities that have been added or modified by looking at `ObjectStateManager`, those are the ones that will be saved.

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)
```

If it is the `DbContext` that you deal with, use following code to get `ObjectContext` from it:

```
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext;
var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
```

Use following code to get your newly added worksets:

```
var entries = context.ObjectStateManager
                     .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                     .Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(WorkSet));
```

Comment: What does this accomplish though? I need to see the objects at various points *before* I save. I can't perform my operations as part of a callback when the entity is saving.

Comment: So simply use this code when you need to look at the changes: `context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified)`

Comment: But that'll just give me a collection of all items changed. I need a succinct way of accessing the items I just added to a particular collection.

Comment: `var entries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Where(entry => entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(WorkSet));` your added worksets

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped it would be a little more straightforward but this is good enough to get me what I need. Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure. I first thought you need to know changes right before saving them, `"see my changes in the entity before I persist them to the database via SaveChanges"`, and answered accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

`_entity.WorkSet` implements `IQueryable`, so calling `Count()` will cause an sql query. There'e no records in database until you call `SaveChanges`, so it will return 0.
If you want to refer added objects before saving changes, use this code:

```
_entity.WorkSet.Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged).Where(e => e.Entity is WorkSet).Select(e => e.Entity as WorkSet).Count();
```

I suppose, you're using EF 1, if you move to a newer version, there's a simpler solution:

```
_entity.WorkSet.Local.Count();
```

Comment: What version was that added in?

Comment: EF 4.1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check that out. But for now, what you (and Andrew) have posted is enough to get me by. Thanks!